# how to return list in asp.net to a json post

Tags: asp.net, json, response

So in my web service i get the data from textboxes search it in database and create letter objects.Then add those objects to a list.my question is how do i return the list to my web page and create divs. for example if service finds 5 letters how i do i return them and create 5 different divs with their data.Thanks in advance

```
   public Letter(string lid, string companyname, string personname, string email, string fax, string phone, string industryname, string teamname, string sender, string statusname, string description, string date)
       {
            LID = lid;
            CompanyName = companyname;
            PersonName = personname;
            Email = email;
            Fax = fax;
            Phone = phone;
            IndustryName = industryname;
            TeamName = teamname;
            Sender = sender;
            StatusName = statusname;
            Description = description;
            Date = date;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to decorate your web services with ScriptService attribute and it will return response in raw json format. For more info check it out [here](http://encosia.com/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/) and you also want to check out [this](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/).

Once you get Json response, you can do something like [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/96/Handling-JSON-Arrays-returned-from-ASP.NET-Web-Services-with-jQuery) to render the output as per your requirement. It's not exactly what you're looking for but it will give you an idea how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

In .net 3.5 you can create json by using the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer otherwise you have to do it manually or by a 3rd party component.